# Почему return ничего не возвращает?

Tags: kotlin, return

В аргумент функции прописывается строка. Дальше идет проверка, если x-вый элемент строки есть в массиве, то n прибавляется.

На выходе должно получиться:

```
"0/53"
"11/65"
```

Но ничего этого нет. Почему?

```
    fun printerError(s: String): String {
        val arr = listOf("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m");
        var x = 0
        var n = 0
        while(x < s.length) {
            if (arr.indexOf(s[x].toString())>=0) {
                n+=1
            }
            x++
        }
        return ((s.length-n).toString()+ "/" + s.length.toString())
    }
    printerError("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm")
    printerError("kkkwwwaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmxyzuuuuu")
```

Comment: Как вы решили, что "функция ничего не возвращает". А вы пробовали что-то делать с возвращаемым значением? Сейчас вы просто игнорируете возвращаемое значение функции. Чтобы как-то дальше работать с ним, присвойте, например, к новой переменной: `val a = printerError("...")`

Answer (score 0):

Ваша программа не выводит результат работы функции на экран. Попробуйте вывести результат с помощью стандартной функции [`println`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html):

```kotlin
val result = printerError("...")
println(result)
```